# How can I get the planes that have been more than once in the same airport in the same day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this database:

```
Plane({Plate(PK), PlaneName});
Flight({FlightNumber(PK), Plate(FK), From, To, Date});
```

And what I want to do is get the PlaneName of the planes that have been more than once in the same airport in the same day. What I mean is , if an airplane has been twice or more in the same airport int the same day, than, it should appear. It shouldn't matter if the plane has been there in the "FROM" or "TO" column.

P.E:

```
PLATE     FLIGHTFROM      FLIGHTTO     DATE

 123          NY             CA        02/03   <---
 211          TX             AZ        02/01   <---
 111          LA             WA        01/30
 123          CA             FL        02/03   <---
 211          AZ             NY        02/01   <---
```

I tried this query, but it didn't work as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.planename
FROM planes p
JOIN (SELECT plate, from AS airport, date 
FROM flights
INTERSECT
SELECT plate, to, date
FROM flights) b ON b.plate = p.plate
```

Comment: "Plate", or "Plane"?

Comment: Also, Plate `123` was only in the `CA` Airport _**once**_ on 2/3. It had two flights, but it arrived at the airport and then left a little later. That's still just **one visit**.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS It seems likely that FlightTo & FlightFrom are temporary named tables that you have not explained.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I get what you say, but in this example, it counts if the same plane is twice in the "flights list", even if it is like you said.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Tables have no order. And the "date" isn't a date & time. So we don't know whether a plane arrived then left or left then arrived on a date with incoming & outgoing flights. So the query as specified can't be written with the given tables. From that & the asker's comments, the specification isn't being given clearly. And your query ordering by date doesn't work for flights on the same date.

Comment: @philipxy I'm assuming the question is sanitized, and the real table has full datetime values. So, yes, an additional cast/convert is needed in the GROUP BY in my answer, but it seems the OP was smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in two steps. First, `UNION` the table to itself, so you can use `FROM` and `TO` values as separate records with the same column name. Then, `GROUP BY` the results, to find entries which occur more than once:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Plate, FlightFrom As AirPort, Date 
    FROM Flight

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Plate, FlightTo As AirPort, Date
    FROM Flight
) G
GROUP BY Plate, AirPort, Date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I worry this won't really give you the data you want. To explain, given the sample data in the question, plate `123` was only in the `CA` airport **one time** on 2/3. It had two flights, but it arrived at the airport and then left a little later. That's still just one visit.

To really know when a plate stopped at an airport twice on the same day, we need to do things a just little different. The structure of the query is similar, but we replace the top section of the `UNION` with a new query to find the *first* `FlightFrom` value for each plate and day. This is the origin, and it's the only case where `FlightFrom` counts as a visit to an airport. Then we continue as before to add all of the `FlightTo` stops and `GROUP BY` the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Plate, FlightFrom As AirPort, Date
    FROM (
        SELECT Plate, FlightFrom, Date
            , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Plate, Date ORDER BY Date ) As seq
        FROM Flight
    ) t
    WHERE seq = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Plate FlightTo As AirPort, Date
    FROM Flight
) G
GROUP BY Plate, AirPort, Date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what I *BELIEVE* you are asking for:

```
INSERT INTO #Plane values (123, 'PLATE 123')
INSERT INTO #Plane values (211, 'PLATE 211')
INSERT INTO #Plane values (111, 'PLATE 111')

INSERT INTO #Flight VALUES(123,'NY','CA', '02/03/20')
INSERT INTO #Flight VALUES(211,'TX','AZ', '02/01/20')
INSERT INTO #Flight VALUES(111,'LA','WA', '01/30/20')
INSERT INTO #Flight VALUES(123,'CA','FL', '02/03/20')
INSERT INTO #Flight VALUES(211,'AZ','NY', '02/01/20')



;WITH CTE as (
        SELECT Plate,FlightFrom,dt 
        FROM #Flight)

SELECT FL2.FlightFrom Airport, P1.Name Plate
FROM #Flight FL1 
INNER JOIN CTE FL2 on FL1.Plate = FL2.Plate 
    AND FL1.FlightTo = FL2.FlightFrom 
    AND FL1.dt = FL2.dt
INNER JOIN #Plane P1 on P1.Plate = FL1.Plate
GROUP BY FL2.FlightFrom, P1.Name
```